# need help in building a logic for single selection in two grids

Tags: c#, logic

i have two grid's and i want to select only one selected item at a time i.e. if A and B are two grids then if i select from A then selected item from B should be unselected and A item should be selected in same click and same for B.

these are my grids on which i bind same event handler of selection changed.

```
CurrentServiceGridView.SelectionChanged +=CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged;
AllServicesGridView.SelectionChanged += CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged;
```

this is how i handle things.

```
private void CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase)(sender)).Name == CurrentServiceGridView.Name)
            {
                    AllServicesGridView.SelectedItem = null;
            }
            else
            {
                    CurrentServiceGridView.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this in this way

```
private void CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase)(sender)).Name == CurrentServiceGridView.Name)
            {
                if (AllServicesGridView.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    AllServicesGridView.SelectionChanged -= CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged;
                    AllServicesGridView.SelectedItem = null;
                    AllServicesGridView.SelectionChanged += CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (CurrentServiceGridView.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    CurrentServiceGridView.SelectionChanged -= CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged;
                    CurrentServiceGridView.SelectedItem = null;
                    CurrentServiceGridView.SelectionChanged += CurrentServiceGridView_SelectionChanged;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle click events of both grids and within those events you should check for activecontrol e.g.

```
        if(this.ActiveControl==yourgrid1)
            //yourgrid2.selecteditem=null
```

i hope it helps.